# How to calculate Scale Factor in AutoScaleMode.Font?

Tags: .net, winforms

I have winform app written in C# (VS2019).
User can change App font size. Forms controls resize perfectly but dynamically created controls after forms showed.
In the code, we fix size and position of controls like buttons, textbox... I know that sizes an positions have to changed accordingly to font size but I do not know the formula to calculate the scale factor.
Please help!

```
            _btnRunsmt = new Button();
            _btnRunsmt.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Top | AnchorStyles.Left;
            _btnRunsmt.Location = new Point(100, 200);
            _btnRunsmt.Name = "btnRunsmt";
            _btnRunsmt.Text = "Click me";
            _btnRunsmt.Size = new Size(100, 30);
            Controls.Add(_btnRunsmt);
```

Comment: You have a Panel there (is it?), you can set it to AutoSize and set `AutoSizeMode` to `GrowAndShrink`, so it will adapt to the size of the Controls it hosts. You can also use TableLayoutPanels and FlowLayoutPanels that also auto-size to their content (or resize the hosted Controls when they're resized). If you need to handle autoscale features, you have to separate your Controls in different, possibly nested, containers that autosize themselves and use the Docking / Anchoring features *wisely*.

Comment: Panel is just a sample, normally they are buttons

Comment: Well, when you add a new Button, it will scale itself using the Font of its Parent when the Font Size changes. The Font is inherited if not set explicitly. -- It's not clear why you're hard-coding a specific Size. Is that sort of a *template* Size? The initial size of *something else*? Buttons (and other Controls) AutoSize and AutoScale based on their content. If you want all the Buttons to have the same size, add your Buttons to the cells of a TableLayoutPanel. Otherwise, let them AutoSize. It depends on what kind of layout you want to achieve. You can also define a custom LayoutEngine...

Comment: In my App, there are some buttons order textbox created dynamically